# When should tf.add(t, 0) be used instead of tensor t directly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In [tensorflow.contrib.slim.batch_norm](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L625), `math_ops.add(moving_mean, 0)` is used to copy the value of `moving_mean`, which is [passed to `nn.moments`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L629) subsequently.

Would it be a problem if we just pass `moving_mean` to `nn.moments` directly?

Are there any guidelines on the use of *copy* operation (`tf.add(t, 0)`)?

Comment: This was added in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e78fadb2). The effect is that it copies value of t, so that if another worker modifies the value of t in parallel, it will be unaffected and will use old value for the tf.moments computation.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thank you for sharing ways to find the answer. It's quite helpful to examine the commit logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the order in which moving_mean is updated, could cause the gradients to use the updated version of moving_mean, instead of the original moving_mean used as shift. So to make sure the same value is used in the forward pass and in the backward pass we make an explicit copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information about it around, but it may be used to convert a tensor reference to a regular tensor. Their behavior differ when you push them to the queue (if the tensor reference changes the value of the tensor). You can read more about it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668712/enqueue-and-increment-variable-in-tensor-flow).